# Utilising forms in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql

I'm currently working on a website for guitarists where a user registers, enters details such as level of experience, areas they hope to work on etc.
They are then given a list of websites suited to their interests as well as a list of tutors (This list will be sourced from a MySQL database).
At the moment I'm trying to figure out how I will utilize the forms in the page where the users enter their details. For example, where will I store the website details for the answers and how will I tell the website to fetch the inputted information?
I would appreciate any help available and any further questions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're really starting from scratch. I'd stat watching something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdAfILoJWcI Its a Harvard class that kind of gives the dynamic website lay of the land. Though, I'd say the main answer to your question is "PHP".

Comment: How much work do you want to do? You can probably grab some kind of starter kit and get a jump on some of the basics, and that would allow you to customize it too. You're going to need something server-side to process and store input too. Are you creating a storefront, a blog, or a community?

Comment: @Tim As much work as is required really. I have all the HTML and CSS done, just need the JavaScript now

Comment: There's an AJAX method in the jQuery framework with several options for passing data depending on what's on the server. I think you can use JSON or XML. It's well documented on the jQuery site and pretty easy to implement - I think I had it working in about an hour, including reading the docs.